# Ошибка при попытке выполнить grunt build c node v.7.0.0 и npm v.4.0.2

Tags: javascript, npm, node.js, grunt

При попытке выполнить grunt build вылетает следующая ошибка:

> Loading "bower-concat.js" tasks...ERROR
>   >> Error: Cannot find module 'internal/fs'
>   Warning: Task "bower_concat" not found. Use --force to continue.

Зависимости в package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "connect-livereload": "^0.5.3",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "^0.11.2",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^0.11.3",
    "grunt-contrib-livereload": "^0.1.2",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "",
    "http-server": "^0.6.1",
    "jshint": "^2.8.0",
    "grunt-bower-concat": "^0.6.0",
    "grunt-bower-task": "^0.4.0",
    "grunt-cli": "^0.1.13",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^0.5.1",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "^0.14.0",
    "grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "^0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^0.11.0",
    "grunt-usemin": "^3.1.1"
}
```

Gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({

        clicknet: {
            app: 'app',
            dist: 'dist'
        },

        connect: {
            options: {
                port: 9000,
                // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
                hostname: '0.0.0.0',
                livereload: 35729,
                base: 'app'
            },
            livereload: {
                options: {
                    open: true
                }
            }
        },

        watch: {
            gruntfile: {
                files: ['Gruntfile.js']
            },
            scripts: {
                files: '<%= clicknet.app %>/style/**/*.css',
                options: {
                    interrupt: true
                }
            }
        },

        jshint: {
            options: {
                node: true,
                jshintrc: '.jshintrc'
            },
            all: {
                src: [
                    '<%= clicknet.app %>/components/**/*.js',
                    '<%= clicknet.app %>/shared/**/*.js'
                ]
            }
        },

        copy: {
            dist: {
                files: [
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: 'app',
                        dest: '<%= clicknet.dist %>',
                        src: [
                            '**/*.html',
                            'shared/directives/**/*.html',
                            'images/**/*',
                            'font/**/*',
                            '!bower_components/**'
                        ]
                    }/*,
                     {
                     expand: true,
                     cwd: 'app/bower_components/jquery-ui/themes/base/images/',
                     src: '**',
                     dest: '<%= clicknet.dist %>/style/images',
                     flatten: true
                     }*/
                ]
            }
        },

        clean: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    dot: true,
                    src: [
                        '.tmp',
                        '<%= clicknet.dist %>/{,*/}*',
                        '!<%= clicknet.dist %>/.git{,*/}*'
                    ]
                }]
            }
        },

        useminPrepare: {
            html: '<%= clicknet.app %>/index.html',
            options: {
                dest: '<%= clicknet.dist %>',
                flow: {
                    html: {
                        steps: {
                            js: ['concat', 'uglify'],
                            css: ['cssmin']
                        },
                        post: {}
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        usemin: {
            html: ['<%= clicknet.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
            css: ['<%= clicknet.dist %>/style/{,*/}*.css'],
            options: {
                assetsDirs: [
                    '<%= clicknet.dist %>',
                    '<%= clicknet.dist %>/images',
                    '<%= clicknet.dist %>/style'
                ]
            }
        },

        concat: {
            js: {
                files: [
                    {
                        dest: '.tmp/scripts/main.js',
                        src: [
                            '<%= clicknet.app %>/app.js',
                            '<%= clicknet.app %>/app.prod.config.js',
                            '<%= clicknet.app %>/app.info.prod.service.js',
                            '<%= clicknet.app %>/components/**/*.js',
                            '<%= clicknet.app %>/shared/**/*.js'
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            css: {
                files: [
                    {
                        src: [
                            'style/*.css',
                            'bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css',
                            'bower_components/perfect-scrollbar/css/perfect-scrollbar.min.css',
                            'bower_components/slick-carousel/slick/slick.css'
                        ],
                        dest: '.tmp/style/main.css'
                    }
                ]
            }
        },

        cssmin: {
            css: {
                src: '.tmp/style/main.css',
                dest: '<%= clicknet.dist %>/style/main.min.css'
            }
        },

        uglify: {
            options: {
                mangle: false
            },

            js: {
                files: {
                    '<%= clicknet.dist %>/scripts/main.min.js': '.tmp/scripts/main.js'
                }
            },

            bower: {
                options: {
                    compress: true
                },
                files: {
                    '<%= clicknet.dist %>/scripts/vendor.min.js': '.tmp/scripts/vendor.js'
                }
            }
        },

        bower_concat: {
            options: {
                separator: '\r\n'
            },
            all: {
                dest: '.tmp/scripts/vendor.js',
                bowerOptions: {
                    relative: false
                }
            }
        },

        bower: {
            install: {
                options: {
                    copy: false
                }
            }
        },

        htmlmin: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    collapseWhitespace: true,
                    conservativeCollapse: true,
                    collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
                    removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
                    removeOptionalTags: true
                },
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= clicknet.dist %>',
                    src: [
                        '**/*.html'
                    ],
                    dest: '<%= clicknet.dist %>'
                }]
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-livereload');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-usemin');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-bower-task');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-bower-concat');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-htmlmin');


    grunt.registerTask('serve', 'Compile then start a connect web server', function () {
        grunt.task.run([
            'connect:livereload',
            'watch'
        ]);
    });

    grunt.registerTask('build', [
        'clean:dist',
        'bower:install',
        'useminPrepare',
        'bower_concat',
        'concat',
        'uglify:js',
        'uglify:bower',
        'cssmin',
        'copy',
        'usemin',
        'htmlmin'
    ]);
};
```

- Версия node 7.0.0
- Версия npm 4.0.2
- Windows 10

Как пытался решить эту проблему:

1. Чистил кэш `npm cache clean`
2. Удалял глобальные node_modules и node_modules проекта. Устанавливал заново и получал ту же ошибку

Answer (score 1):

Решение проблемы: в package.json заменить `"grunt-bower-concat": "^0.6.0"` на `"grunt-bower-concat": "^1.0.0"`